# Google drive api ver3 how share on my web page

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, google-drive-api

Can somebody help me? I could add the file to my webPage in version 2 like this (img1): `drive.files().get(fileID).execute().getAlternateLink());` How i can do this in ver3 ?? All of this method return null: getWebContentLink ,getWebViewLink,getThumbnailLink
2) How i can get full access auth? Google examples doesn't works
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZbkA.png)

Comment: "webContentLink string A link for downloading the content of the file in a browser. This is only available for files with binary content in Drive. " Source: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource There is also "webViewLink string A link for opening the file in a relevant Google editor or viewer in a browser. "

Comment: .getWebContentLink() is null ( the same file that I used for getAlternateLink()

Comment: Is it a binary file? It is stated, that this only is available for binaries. If not, you may try webViewLink?

Comment: It's .doc file (created in google docs). getWebViewLink is also return null ///

Comment: This is working fine for me. I was able to get the webViewLink just fine for docs. I suggest try running it from the [API's explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/). If you can update your question with full request and response here.

Comment: google it's a f**cking crazy api...

Answer (score 0):

In [Drive v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk), to retrieve metadata properties (i.e. WebViewLink, thumbnailLink,emailAddress, etc.), you will only need to specify the individual `fields` required by the app.

Try something like this (example in Python):

```
file_id ='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
file = service.files().get(fileId=file_id, fields='webViewLink').execute()
    print 'Title: %s' % file['webViewLink']
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Hello! Method "get" has only one parameter

Comment: Yes, required parameter is just one. You can also set specific fields. As shown here. I believe in Java, it should be something like this: driveService.files().update(fileId, fileMetadata).setFields("webViewLink").execute();